# Passing Parameters from View to Controller when a hyperlink is clicked and return parameters from Controller to view

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is View file. I am trying to pass- `"$row['ISBN'] . ':SearchByAuthor:' . $Author"- abc:SearchByAuthor:aka -` value to function `increment_author` to controller file.

```
<?php
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php
echo $row['ISBN'];
?></td>
    <td><?php
echo $row['name'];
?></td>
    <td><?php
echo $row['title'];
?></td>
    <td><?php
echo $row['year'];
?></td>
    <td><?php
echo $row['price'];
?></td>
    <td><?php
echo $row['publisher'];
?></td>
    <td><?php
echo $row['number'];
?></td>
    <td> <a href="<?php
echo base_url();
?>/increment_author/<?php
echo $row['ISBN'] . ':SearchByAuthor:' . $Author;
?>">
    Add to cart</a></td>
</tr>
<?php
?>
```

This is contoller file and I am doing some calculations and trying the same to return to above search page, which is view. However, it's not working. I am trying to convert native php code to codeIgniter framework. Please help me out in passing parameters from Controller to View and vice versa. Thanks in Advance

```
   public function increment_author($SearchByAuthor)
    {
        session_start();

    $db = new mysqli('localhost','root','','cheapbook') or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');
     mysqli_set_charset($db, 'utf8');


    if(isset($SearchByAuthor))
        {
    //        echo $_GET['add'];
            $pieces=explode(":", $SearchByAuthor);

            $quantity="SELECT D.ISBN, D.title, sum(D.number) number FROM
            (SELECT A.ISBN, title, number number FROM 
            book A, Stocks B  WHERE A.ISBN='$pieces[0]' and
            A.ISBN=B.ISBN)D
            GROUP BY D.ISBN, D.title";

            $result = mysqli_query($db,$quantity);



            while($quantity_row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
                if($_SESSION['cart_'.$pieces[0]])
                {
                    $chan=0;
                }
                else 
                {
                    $_SESSION['cart_count']+=1;
                }
                if($quantity_row['number']!=$_SESSION['cart_'.$pieces[0]] )
                {
                        $_SESSION['cart_'.$pieces[0]]+=1;
                        $_SESSION["cartTotal"]+=1;

                }
            }
            $data['SearchByAuthor']=$pieces[0];
        }
        //header("location:search_vi?SearchByAuthor=".$pieces[0]);
        //$data['SearchByAuthor']=$pieces[0];
        $this->load->view('search',$data);

    }
```

Comment: Use a form with hidden fields - not a link. Will be much easier. Just echo out whatever you need in the form submit button.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use **session_start** actually you should use [Session Library](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#initializing-a-session). 
Also there is a whole [Database](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/index.html) layer in CI.

Try to debug your problem in more details. Check if your $data variable contains proper result, and in your view this will be visible via $SearchByAuthor variable.